# Get Next and Previous Tags (AwesomeWM)

Tags: awesome-wm

Is there a way to get the next or previous tag in AwesomeWM Lua Config?

Reason :- I want to get the next or previous tag to set the focused clients tag to it and then move to the tag.
I know there is awful.tag.viewnext which moves to the next tag but unsure about how to get the tag it will move to to set this on a client.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well... yes, there is a way, but there is not a completely trivial one.

First, let's look at the default config. What existing functionality has to get next/previous tags? That is the mouse wheel on the taglist:

https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/blob/7a759432d3100ff6870e0b2b427e3352bf17c7cc/awesomerc.lua#L160-L161

So, how does `awful.tag.viewnext` and `viewprev` get the next tag? These functions just call `viewidx` with an `idx` of 1 or -1, e.g.:

https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/blob/7a759432d3100ff6870e0b2b427e3352bf17c7cc/lib/awful/tag.lua#L1494

So, `awful.tag.viewidx` can do what we want. How does it do it?

It gets a table of all un-hidden tags, finds the index of the currently selected tag and then uses `gears.math.cycle` to compute the index of the tag with the requested offset.

https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/blob/7a759432d3100ff6870e0b2b427e3352bf17c7cc/lib/awful/tag.lua#L1452-L1469

For you, something like the following should do the trick:

```
function get_tag_at_offset(i, s)
    s = screen[s or awful.screen.focused()]
    local tags = s.tags
    local showntags = {}
    for _, t in pairs(tags) do
        if not awful.tag.getproperty(t, "hide") then
            table.insert(showntags, t)
        end
    end
    for k, t in ipairs(showntags) do
        if t == sel then
            return showntags[gears.math.cycle(#showntags, k + i)]
        end
    end
end
```

The above function can be used like `get_tag_at_offset(1)` to get the next tag and with argument `-1` for the previous. Where possible, I would recommend to also pass in a screen via the second argument.

Also, all of this is completely untested and just written on the spot. There could very well be typos and other mistakes in here.